# What happened to more that 110 thousand of closed votes?

Tags: discussion, review

Few days ago there were more than 120 thousand of Closed Votes in the review section. Today when I checked this section there is only 8 thousand there.

What happened to this votes (I highly doubt that they were reviewed in a few days)? Is it some new change in review process, site design or were they really reviewed?

Comment: We had a barbeque.

Comment: I still can not understand, it is written that 15,137 post were reviewed. Also it impressive, but still far away from 120 000 that were in the queue.

Comment: they barbequed the list

Comment: @Amaterasu I got it, but when I was reading the original post, it was written that 15k posts were reviewed, and I remember that it was 120k of them.

Comment: i think there has been an absolute solid effort and the number came down fast

Comment: @Salvador: Yes, there were 120K of them. Read the post: "Now, **only questions with at least 4 votes/flags are listed** in the close review queue." So clearly there were only 15K questions with at least 4 votes, and they're what were listed. The graph in the link shows the large spike in close question reviews after that post was made. (See the large upturn at the right end?) Everything is quite clear. Read the linked post.